# Add a header in top and close button in right side to dismiss the ModalBottomSheet jetpackcompose in android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

[image]Here is the code

```
ModalBottomSheet(
    onDismissRequest = onDismiss,
    windowInsets = WindowInsets.ime,
    dragHandle = { BottomSheetDefaults.DragHandle() },
    containerColor = Color.White,
    content = {

Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Text(text = "Title of ModalBottomSheet")
        IconButton(
            modifier = Modifier.offset(x = 8.dp, y = 8.dp),
            onClick = { onDismiss() }
        ) {
            Icon(asset = Icons.Filled.Close)
        }
    }
}
```

}
)

Answer (score 1):

You can place whatever Composable you would like into the `content` slot. Using the [`offset`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Modifier#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).offset(androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp)) Modifier, you can place Composables independently of any predefined padding. 
If you want to display a close button in the top right area, you can try the following code:

```
content = {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
               .fillMaxWidth()
               .offset(y = -12.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter),
                text = "Title of ModalBottomSheet"
            )
            IconButton(
                modifier = Modifier
                   .align(Alignment.TopEnd)
                   .offset(y = -12.dp),
                onClick = { onDismiss() }
            ) {
                Icon(asset = Icons.Filled.Close)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

You can adjust the `offset`s as you wish.

Alternatively, you could try to add the whole `Column` Composable into the `dragHandle` slot:

```
dragHandle = {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(4.dp)
    ) {
       // ...
    }

}
```

**Disclaimer:**

What you are trying to achieve violates the Material Design Principles, and I would discourage you from overriding default paddings.

Comment: problem is the close icon is not top right corner there is some space by deafult like 16 dp or more

Comment: I have marked in red where i want title and close button, the result of your code us attached in pic

Comment: I edited my post, it should give you a good idea how to achieve your desired layout.

Comment: What is the best solution to achieve the result

Comment: The solution that I posted is fine for itself. I think however if you add a Button or Text, you should respect the default padding.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the drag handle then use your own close button in the content, code should look like this

```
ModalBottomSheet(
  onDismissRequest = { onDismiss() },
  sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
     skipPartiallyExpanded = true
  ),
  dragHandle =  {}
) {
//Content you like
}
```

drag handle is the small bar you see at the top, it takes up space at the top